# [Spring]create an abstract bean for a non abstract class

Tags: spring

with this config for Spring framework (4.2.5.RELEASE version):

```
<bean id="Filter" class="net....StreamFilter" abstract="true">
    <property name="begin" value="3" />
    <property name="end" value="5" />
</bean>
<bean id="D0Filter" parent="Filter">
    <property name="value" value="D0" />
</bean>
```

and my StreamFilter class is like:

```
public class StreamFilter  {

    /** debut du filtre */
    private int begin;

    /** fin du filtre */
    private int end;

    private String value;

    public Object convert(@Body final Exchange exchange) {
        // my code
    }

   //
   // getter & setter
   //
}
```

i have this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanIsAbstractException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'DFIFilter': Bean definition is abstract  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.checkMergedBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:285)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
>
> ......

thanks for your responses

Comment: The problem is with the bean DFIFilter. You haven't posted anything about it.

Comment: i rename the DFIFilter to D0Filter to remove secific company code but i forget it in the stacktrace.

Comment: the error wille be Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanIsAbstractException: Error creating bean with name 'D0IFilter': Bean definition is abstract at ....

Comment: and the D0Filter  bean will extend the Filter bean